# Matlab - How can I save the steps (summary of the steps) of a fmincon optimization?

Tags: matlab, optimization, rotation

I have a `fmincon` optimization in my script which aligns geometric surfaces in a Cartesian coordinate system.

```
function fDiffLiRe = opt_Teil2(phi)

global xNeg yNeg xPos yPos stepsX yyPos yyNeg fLiDiff fReDiff  fistLi fistRe fsollLi fsollRe xxxPos xxxNeg yyyPos
global yyyNeg
global interpolationsmethode

%Coordinates are rotated through Phi
%left geometrical shape rotated
xxxNeg=xNeg*cos(phi)+yNeg*sin(phi);
yyyNeg=-xNeg*sin(phi)+yNeg*cos(phi);

%right geometrical shape rotated 
xxxPos=xPos*cos(phi)+yPos*sin(phi);
yyyPos=-xPos*sin(phi)+yPos*cos(phi);

%rotated coordinates are interpolated
yyPos = interp1(yyyPos,xxxPos,stepsX, interpolationsmethode);
yyNeg = interp1(yyyNeg,xxxNeg,stepsX, interpolationsmethode);

%area of each geometrical shape is calculated
%left
fistLi=trapz(stepsX,yyNeg);

%target size of the left shape
fsollLi=-0.93;
fLiDiff=fsollLi-fistLi;

%right
fistRe=trapz(stepsX,yyPos');

%target size of the right shape
fsollRe=0.93
fReDiff=fsollRe-fistRe;  

%sum of the Deviation of the target sizes is minimized
fDiffLiRe=(fReDiff+fLiDiff)^2;
  end
```

The optimization works fine and returns the correctly rotated coordinates `yyPos` and `yyNeg`. I would now like to return the total angle `phi` the coordinates have been rotated through. How can I do that? The variable `phi` only shows the last step of the optimization

Comment: This is what [output functions](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html) are for. There are plenty of examples in the documentation. Good luck!

Comment: thank you! I tried to add the Output fuction to my code using the example you posted... I posted my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345428/matlab-fmincon-optimization-output-function Do you know why the Output funciton isn't working? The optimization works fine. Thank you!!