# Matlab - fmincon optimization output function

Tags: matlab, optimization, rotation

I have a fmincon optimization in my script which aligns geometric surfaces in a Cartesian coordinate System by (iterative) rotation of the coordinates through the angle phi.
I now want to save the Output of the optimization by using an Output function. But it only Returns me an Matrix of 1,1,1,1,1...
The optimization works fine!!

This is the function I call to run the optimization and show the Output. I used this [example](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html?requestedDomain=nl.mathworks.com) to write the ouput function but I think I have to adapt the variables x and fval to my example...

```
function [history,searchdir] = runopt_Teil2

global stepsX yyPos 
global fDiffLiRe phi2

% Set up shared variables with OUTFUN
history.x = [];
history.fval = [];
searchdir = [];

% call optimization
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'OutputFcn',@outfun,'Display', 'off', 'Algorithm','sqp','MaxIter',20);

r=1;
ss=[0 1];
oo=0;

while (ss(1)<ss(2))

o=1+oo;
Startwert=[0.05 -0.05];

[phi2,fDiffLiRe,output]=fmincon(@(phi)opt_Teil2(phi),Startwert(r),[],[],[],[],-0.1,0.1,[],options);

ss=yyPos(size(stepsX));
r=r+1;
if (ss(1)>ss(2))
    oo=1;
    break
end
end

 function stop = outfun(x,optimValues,state)
     stop = false;

     switch state
         case 'init'
             hold on
         case 'iter'
         % Concatenate current point and objective function
         % value with history. x must be a row vector.
           history.fval = [history.fval; optimValues.fval];
           history.x = [history.x; x];
         % Concatenate current search direction with 
         % searchdir.
           searchdir = [searchdir;... 
                        optimValues.searchdirection'];
         % plot(x(1),x(2),'o');
         % Label points with iteration number and add title.
         % Add .15 to x(1) to separate label from plotted 'o'
         %  text(x(1)+.15,x(2),... 
                num2str(optimValues.iteration);
           title('Sequence of Points Computed by fmincon');
         case 'done'
             hold off
         otherwise
     end
 end

end
```

This is the optimization function

```
function fDiffLiRe=opt_Teil2(phi) 

global xNeg yNeg xPos yPos stepsX yyPos yyNeg fLiDiff fReDiff  fistLi fistRe fsollLi fsollRe xxxPos xxxNeg yyyPos
global yyyNeg
global interpolationsmethode

%Rotation of coordinates
xxxPos=xPos*cos(phi)+yPos*sin(phi);
yyyPos=-xPos*sin(phi)+yPos*cos(phi);

xxxNeg=xNeg*cos(phi)+yNeg*sin(phi);
yyyNeg=-xNeg*sin(phi)+yNeg*cos(phi);

% Interpolation
yyPos = interp1(yyyPos,xxxPos,stepsX, interpolationsmethode);
yyNeg = interp1(yyyNeg,xxxNeg,stepsX, interpolationsmethode);

%Shape surfaces left
fistLi=trapz(stepsX,yyNeg);

fsollLi=-0.93;
fLiDiff=fsollLi-fistLi;

%Shape surfaces right
fistRe=trapz(stepsX,yyPos');
fsollRe=0.93;
fReDiff=fsollRe-fistRe;

fDiffLiRe=(fReDiff+fLiDiff)^2;
```

Could you please tell me where I made a mistake? 
Thank you very much! Best regards,
Oensen

Comment: I can't run this; I don't have values for most of the global variables. Can you please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?